# AODV c++ implementation

Tags: c++

Can someone help me to find the variable concerning the id of a node in the file aodv.cc exactly in the function:

```
AODV::sendRequest(nsaddr_t dst)
```

I'm working on modification of AODV protocol, so I need to get the velocity of a node. For that I implement a function `get_Velocity(id, time);` which has as parameters the ID of the node and the current time.

This function should be called in the function's send request, send reply of the protocol aodv.

I'm facing the following problem: How to get the id of the node?

I thought in the beginning that is index but index refer the ip address of the node.

Comment: You should probably add some info to the question, so that someone who does not know this AODV, whatever it is, can take a shot at answering. Additionally, you should show more code, at least a compilable function (except the part you don't know how to do, obviously), and preferably an SSCCE (http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this:

1. Use an IDE with C++ parsing based autocompletion/intellisense, such as Visual Studio or Qt Creator.
2. Either convert you current project to that IDE, or create dummy project.
3. In that project, go to or code where you have something like that `nsaddr_t dst` in scope.
4. As a new statement, write `dst.`, and if some autocompletion widget does not pop up automatically after the dot, then press *control+space* (or whatever triggers the autocompletion in your IDE).
5. From the autocompletion widget, try to find some method which does what you want directly, or which returns some other likely object value/reference/pointer, and continue by performing autocompletion on it, and so on.

Or just read the docs...

Answer (score 0):

Actually by modifying aodv.cc itself you cannot get velocity of the nodes. you have to create function **(get_Velocity)** in mobilenode.cc (ns2.xx/commom/) to dispaly the velocity. now you can call your **(get_Velocity)** function from aodv.cc.